# Message Broker with synchronous delivery

Tags: message, synchronous, mqtt, broker

we are implementing (or more reimplementing) a distributed software system. What we have are different processes (possibly running on different computers) that should communicate with each other (let's call these clients). We don't want them to directly communicate with each other, but instead use some kind of message broker.

Since we like to avoid implementing the message broker ourselves we would like to use an existing implementation. But we don't find a protocol or system that fully fulfilles our requirements.

MQTT with its publish-subscribe-mechanism seems nice and could even be used for point-to-point communication (where some specific topics are only subscribed by certain clients).
But it is (like JSM, STOMP, etc.) asynchronous. The sender sends a message into the broker and doesn't know whether it is ever delivered to it's recipient. We want that the sender gets informed about a successful delivery or an elapsed timeout (when no one is receiving the message).

Is there some protocol/implementation available that provides such synchronous messaging functionality?
(It would be nice however if asynchronous delivery would be possible, too)

Comment: By definition MQTT is pub/sub and is not a 1 to 1 messaging system, it is 1 to many. The publishing side really shouldn't care how many people have received the message (as it could potentially be flooded with an infinite number of received notifications).  MQTT may not be the right choice of protocol for the system you describe

Comment: @hardillb Yep, that's why I am asking for alternative protocols. MQTT seems like a very good protocol that unfortunately doesn't match out requirements.

Comment: It is clear why MQTT is not suitable, but this question is somewhat vague about what is acceptable.  You haven't provided detail about your requirements why you would select between the many request/repsonse protocols such as COAP, REST, XMPP, or CORBA.  A proxy would put another machine in the middle of any of these.  What exactly do you need from the machine in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

The messaging by default is ( usually ) asynchronous .
You can considerer RabbitMQ, it contains the following features:

1. Publisher-confirms (in asynchronous way):
   http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/
2. Transaction Commit:
   https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html
3. Messages TTL (to handle time out)
   https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

With this features you can handle the time-out situations and the successful delivery.

If this is not enough you can use the RPC:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: As I understand the first 3 suggestions don't help, since I can only be sure about successful delivery to the _broker_, not the intended recipient. However, RPC with RabbitMQ may be an option. We will eveluate this.